# Can I add more stuff to my fermenting Sauerkraut jar?

Tags: vegetables

So, I have a jar of sauerkraut fermenting, and today (2days into fermentation) due to my curiosity, I opened the jar a bit to taste the kraut. It tasted quite nice, the taste change already happend to the onions I think. So, now after eating, there is a bit of gap in the jar. Could I add more stuff into my Krautjar? My concern is if new stuff would disrupt the fermentation somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work fine. Adding ingredients this early on, the fermentation time will be roughly the same as if you had not added them. (If it has been near the end of fermentation, there would have been more of a "reset” on the clock.)